# Can you edit a file on a remote computer when there is no editor available?

Tags: text-editors, telnet

I have an old Synology NAS which which I can only telnet in to and I want to edit a config file.  Unfortunately there is no editing software at all; no vi, nano, vim nothing.

Is there a way to use the editing software at the local end to edit a file at the remote end?  Or is there another way perhaps to make edits to the file?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have busybox? If so, try busybox vi file.to.edit.  If not, surely as a NAS you can copy files to the shared part, edit them on your local device and copy them back? If you provide your model, you have much more chance of a non-generic answer.

Comment: Do you have an ftp client in the NAS? If so maybe you can run an ftp server and ftp files to and from it. Also, if you can enable SSH on it you should be able to SCP files to and from it.

Comment: If you can get into some shell, I have never met a Linux that didn't have at least [ed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ed) available, but it's a pain to use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have write permission (without which editing is pointless), cou can just overwrite it with whatever you want:

- Create the new file with whatever software you want and store it in the NAS share
- Use `cat /local/path/to/file/in/share >/local/path/to/file/to/overwrite` to replace it.

Other options include:

- Use `nc` to download the file from your PC to the device (it is included in most firmware images)
- Use `echo -e "..." >/local/path/to/file/to/overwrite` with the whole text of the file included in the `echo` and careful escaping
- Use a sequence of `sed` statements

Comment: That's a good idea but I don't believe it can be done in this case.  The reason I am trying to edit the config file is that it doesn't have an OS at this time but basic firmware which allows enough connectivity to download and configure the OS.  I'm just not sure I can access the share as this has not been created yet.  I have tried removing the HDD and using a reader but It would appear the firmware is residing on the board and not on the HDD...